# Cliente - Webservice SIPSA

Tags: python, zeep

El caso es sobre el método `consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadr()`, pide un parámetro numérico para realizar la consulta. No se como implementarlo. Todos los demás ya están funcionando y su demostración operativa está en el repositorio: https://github.com/oigonzalezp2024/cliente-webservice-sipsa/tree/main

```
# fuente: https://github.com/oigonzalezp2024/cliente-webservice-sipsa/blob/main/etl/etl.py

def extractData(wsdl:str, serviceMethod:str, arg0:int)->object:
    client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl)
    getService = {}
    if(serviceMethod == "promedioAbasSipsaMesMadr"):
        getService = client.service.promedioAbasSipsaMesMadr()
    elif(serviceMethod == "promediosSipsaCiudad"):
        getService = client.service.promediosSipsaCiudad()
    elif(serviceMethod == "promediosSipsaMesMadr"):
        getService = client.service.promediosSipsaMesMadr()
    elif(serviceMethod == "promediosSipsaParcial"):
        getService = client.service.promediosSipsaParcial()
    elif(serviceMethod == "promediosSipsaSemanaMadr"):
        getService = client.service.promediosSipsaSemanaMadr()
    elif(serviceMethod == "consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadr"):
        getService = client.service.consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadr(arg0 = arg0)
        
    return getService
```

¿Estaría bien así? No he logrado obtener números validos que sirvan para poder hacer test de funcionamiento. Los otros métodos no requieren parámetros. Este si.

```
# Propuesta:

from etl import etl

wsdl = 'https://appweb.dane.gov.co/sipsaWS/SrvSipsaUpraBeanService?WSDL'
serviceMethod = "consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadr"
arg0 = 4
fields = [
    'artiId',
    'artiNombre',
    'enviado',
    'fechaCreacion',
    'fechaIni',
    'fuenId',
    'fuenNombre',
    'futiId',
    'maximoKg',
    'minimoKg',
    'promedioKg',
    'tmpMayoSemId'
]

pathFile = str("./data/consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadr.json")
etl.controller(wsdl, serviceMethod, arg0, fields, pathFile)
```